# What is unicode/unistr.h?

Tags: c++, cryptography

I'm trying to add Beecrypt library to my project, but unfortunately it doesn't compile and demands unicode/unistr.h file, which is not a part of this library. Have you ever run into the same problem? What is that unicode/unistr.h file? Why it is not included into Beecrypt library since it is needed for the library's work? Where am i supposed to download it? I've searched in Google but in vain. Any ideas is highly appreciated

Comment: offtopic question: did you use Beecrypt iunder Linux? If so, how did you compile a cpp code which uses Beecrypt files? TIA :)

Comment: @yak sorry, but i can't help you, i never did it on Linux

Comment: ok, anyway, thanks for the replay, cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are header files from the [International Components for Unicode library](http://site.icu-project.org/download/48), which you can [download](http://site.icu-project.org/download) and link into your project along with Beecrypt.

Answer (score 4):

unistr.h is also installed as part of [GNU libunistring](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/). If you are using yum, you should be able to install it as

> yum install libunistring-devel

Comment: I think it's rather `libicu-dev`

Comment: I have found that installing libunistring-devel installs /usr/include/unistr.h but then the condition unicode/unistr.h is not fulfilled. By installing ```yum install libicu-devel``` it installs /usr/include/unicode/unistr.h which is matching the original request.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04 this worked for me:

```
apt-get install libunistring-dev
```